# jQuery + History API Form Error

Tags: jquery, tapestry, html5-history

Issue: I'm getting an Error that my fields must be enclosed by a form component when hitting the back button after loading a new page. I suspect this is AJAX related as similar errors can arise when updating a zone containing a form. Code as follows:

```
var $j = jQuery;

     $j(document).ready(function(){
      var content;

     content = $j("body");


     //Injects content
     inject = function(href){
      $j.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:7101' + href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
            content.html(data);
            }
       });
   };

    //Back/Forward Support
    $j(window).on('popstate', function(){
        inject(location.pathname);
    });


        $j(".t-data-grid").find("a").click(function(e){
                var href = $j(this).attr('href');

        //Manipulate history
        history.pushState(null, null, href);
        e.preventDefault();

         //Inject Content
         inject(href);
        });
    });
```

I am using Tapestry5-jQuery fyi.

Comment: I suggest you edit the title to reflect the problem not the tools you're using, you(should ?) already mention those tools in tags :)

Comment: replacing the whole `body` isn't much a good usecase for ajax in my opinion, also when the user clicks back/forward button with or without your popstate event the outcome will be the same, in fact it will have better performance without it

Comment: and your `a` click event does what the browser already does

Comment: So here's the thing. Some pages have an ajax zone update with search results which is what I'd like to preserve so that when a user hits back the results are still there without having to resubmit the form. Can you suggest some edits?